# arithmetic overflow twitter newtonsoft json

Tags: json, twitter, json.net

I am parsing twitter's JSON using array of objects. However, I am getting arithmetic overflow error from newtonsoft JSON library.

```
TweetsbyUSCong[] tweetsResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TweetsbyUSCong[]>(queryResult);
```

It has worked couple of times but it has failed more often than not. Thanks in advance for your time. I am using Twitter API v1.1 to pull the JSON feed.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat Twitter IDs as ulong. ID's for Status and User entities are already 64-bit and the List entity ID is planned to be 64-bit soon.